# How to get the name of the current user in Refinery?

Tags: refinerycms

In RefineryCMS, for some functionality I have to store the present logged in user's first name and last name.

How to get logged in user's first name and last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going through this implementation, I found that r`efinery user table does not have column to store first name, last name` or any basic details about user.

So, first step is to create a migration file having first_name, last_name etc as per requirement.

> $ rails generate migration AddFirstNameLastNameToRefineryUsers
>   first_name:string last_name:string

Then run

> $ rake db:migrate

Now, create a decorators for user model.

> Path :: /app/decorators/models/refinery/user_decorator.rb

Create a decorator : [Refinery Documentation Link for Creating Decorator](http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators)

Add this line inside that model

> attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
>
> validates :first_name,:last_name, :presence => true

Now add this line at view area

> - /app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class => 'larger widest' %>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, :class => 'larger widest' %>
  </div>
```

Now, Rails will save the values, when user makes first time login.